# Comparar objetos dentro de Arraylist

Tags: java

Tengo una clase llamada Curso en la cual deberia almacenar alumnos. Estos tienen nombre, telefono y DNI. Cuando quiero agregar un nuevo alumno debería comparar si hay dos DNIs iguales. No esto seguro de como hacer eso.

Clase curso

```
public class Curso{
//Lista
ArrayList curso = new ArrayList(40);


public void agregar(String nombre, double DNI,double telefono){
}}
```

Metodo main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Alumno a1 = new Alumno();
    Alumno a2 = new Alumno();
    a1.agregar("Gabriel", 3132, 41214);
    System.out.println(a1.curso);
    a2.agregar("Juan", 3132, 124141);
    System.out.println(a2.curso);
}
```

Clase alumno

```
class Alumno extends Curso{


//Atributos
private int telefono, DNI,DNI2;
private String nombre;

//Getters y Setters
public double getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public double getDNI(int i) {
    return DNI;
}

public void setDNI(int DNI) {
    this.DNI = DNI;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Supongo que deberia haber una manera de hacer un metodo en la clase Alumno que compare los DNIs pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Bienvenido, Agrega el objeto Alumno  y como creas el ArrayList de objetos Alumno? . Mencionas: " debería comparar si no hay dos DNIs diferentes", no te refieres a comparar para saber si ya existe el DNI?, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega más información a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Pensé que habia copiado la clase Alumno pero me olvidé. Ya la agregué. Mis disculpas. Y si, deberia comparar para saber si ya existe ese DNI

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tu código veo que tienes una confusión con la herencia, al usar `extends`, estas diciendo que alumno hereda de curso, lo cual, no tiene sentido alguno, ya que, un alumno jamás se puede comportar como una curso. Recordar que para saber si una herencia esta bien aplicada, se debería poder reemplazar el hijo por el padre, y el programa, se debería seguir comportando de la misma manera.

Aclarado esto, te indico como debería ser tu código para validar lo que pedís.

El Main deberia ser asi:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
      Curso c1 = new Curso("3ºA","Mañana");
      
      Alumno a1 = new Alumno("11-0000-1111","Pedro Sanchez",35123456);
      Alumno a2 = new Alumno("11-2222-1111","Juan Rodriguez",35123456);// le pongo el mismo dni para que no lo agregue a la lista
      Alumno a3 = new Alumno("11-3333-1111","Emilse Rodas",11111);
           
      if(c1.existeAlumnoConEseDni(a1.getDNI()))
          System.out.println("Existe un alumno con ese DNI, por lo cual, no se va a agregar a la lista");
      else
      {    
          if (c1.agregar(a1))
              System.out.println("Alumno agregado con exito");
          else
              System.out.println("Ocurrio un error al agregar el alumno");
      }
      if(c1.existeAlumnoConEseDni(a2.getDNI()))
          System.out.println("Existe un alumno con ese DNI, por lo cual, no se va a agregar a la lista");
      else
      {    
          if (c1.agregar(a2))
              System.out.println("Alumno agregado con exito");
          else
              System.out.println("Ocurrio un error al agregar el alumno");
      }if(c1.existeAlumnoConEseDni(a3.getDNI()))
          System.out.println("Existe un alumno con ese DNI, por lo cual, no se va a agregar a la lista");
      else
      {    
          if (c1.agregar(a3))
              System.out.println("Alumno agregado con exito");
          else
              System.out.println("Ocurrio un error al agregar el alumno");
      }

      System.out.println("Listado de alumnos: ");
      for(Alumno alu : c1.listaDeAlumnos)
      {
        System.out.println(alu.toString());
      }    
    }
}
```

Clase Alumno:

```
public class Alumno 
{
    private String telefono;//lo declaro string, para no obligar a poner solo numeros.De esta forma se pueden ingresar telefonos con -
    private String nombre;
    private long DNI;//no uso doble, ya que, los DNI deberian ser numeros enteros y el long soporta un numero entero de gran tamaño

    //es buena practica hacer un constructor sin parametros que inicialice los atributos, esto para evitar hacer constructores vacios 
    //cuando se utiliza herencia y tener algun problema
    public Alumno() {
        this.telefono = "N/D";
        this.nombre = "N/D";
        this.DNI = -1;
    }    
    
    //y como hice un constructor sin parametros, tambien hago uno que reciba atributos como parametros
    public Alumno(String telefono, String nombre, long DNI) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.DNI = DNI;
    }
     
    //Aca empiezan los Getters
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public long getDNI() {
        return DNI;
    }
    
    //como veras, no he creado ningun set, ya que, a mi parecer los SETs violan el encapsulamiento.
    //Para poder modificar los atributos, deberiamos crear otro metodo que permita modificar los atributos
    //bajo ciertas condiciones.
    
    public boolean validarDNI(long dni)
    {
        //creo este metodo que va recibir un DNI y lo va a comparar con el DNI del alumno.
        //uso el this para indicar que es el atributo de esta clase y no el DNI
        //que viene por parametro.
        //Creo este metodo dentro del alumno, ya que, es donde esta la info necesaria
        //Hay que agregar el comportamiento lo mas cercano a los datos. En este caso, el DNI, es un atributo del alumno
        //por lo que, le corresponde al alumno validar esto.
        return this.DNI == dni;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno{" + "telefono=" + telefono + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", DNI=" + DNI + '}';
    }
    
}
```

Clase Curso:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Curso     
{
    //para que no quede tan vacio, digo que un curso tiene un 
    // nombre y un turno
    //Ejemplo de esto un curso puede ser 3ºA Turno noche
    String nombre,turno;    
    List<Alumno> listaDeAlumnos;//de esta forma me aseguro que a la lista solo le puedo insertar alumnos
    //al declararla del Tipo List, tengo la libertad de luego crearla del tipo que necesite, ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.
    
    //Al igual que antes, voy a crear 2 constructores, uno con parametros y otros sin
    
    public Curso()
    {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.turno = "";
        this.listaDeAlumnos = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }
    
    public Curso(String nombre, String turno)
    {
       this.nombre = nombre;
        this.turno = turno;
        this.listaDeAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();  
    }        
       
    /*este es el metodo encargado de agregar el alumno a la lista.
    se podria recibir los datos necesarios para crear un alumno y crearlo dentro de este metodo,
    pero no es responsabilidad de este metodo crear el alumno, por lo que vamos a recibir un alumno creado.
    en este metodo tambien podria validar si el DNI existe, pero como dije antes, no es responsabilidad de este metodo
    este metodo solo va a agregar el alumno a la lista.*/
    public boolean agregar(Alumno a)//hago que retorne un booleano para saber si pudo registrar el alumno o no
    {
       return listaDeAlumnos.add(a);
    }
    
    //este va a ser el metodo encargado de validar si existe un alumno con el mismo dni
    public boolean existeAlumnoConEseDni(long dni)
    {  
        boolean encontrado = false;//variable para saber si existe un alumno con ese DNI en la lista

        for(Alumno a : listaDeAlumnos)//esto es un foreach, el cual me sirve para recorrer la lista de alumnos
        {                             // la sintaxis es, for(TipoDeDato nombreVariable : listaARecorrer)
            encontrado = a.validarDNI(dni);//llamo al metodo del alumno y le paso el dni
            if(encontrado)//si encontro un alumno, rompo el ciclo, ya que, no tiene seguir recorriendo la lista
                break;
        }
        return encontrado;//retorno el valor de encontrado
    }
}
```

Estos deberian ser tus resultados luego de correr el main:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar extends solo cuando apliques herencia,para el caso de curso y alumno debes hacer uso de un constructor y como existe una tipo de composición,la clase Curso crea un objeto de la clase Alumno  y la agrega a una base de datos ,solo si no existe dnis duplicados

Clase Curso:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Curso{
private List<Alumno>listaDeAlumnos;
public Curso(){
this.listaDeAlumnos=new ArrayList<>(40);
}
//metodo que crea una nueva instancia de la clase alumno, y agrega a la lista de alumno solo en caso de quue no exista 
//otro alumno con el mismo DNI,para eso asemos uso de una excepcion
public void agregar(String telefono,int dni,String nombre)throws Exception{
Alumno alumno=new Alumno(telefono,dni,nombre);
List<Integer> listaDni = new ArrayList<> ();//creamos una lista interna que almacene solo los dni
  for (Alumno a : this.listaDeAlumnos) {
        listaDni.add (a.getDni ());
   }
boolean existe = listaDni.contains (alumno.getDni ());//hacemos uso del metodo contains para evaluar si existe un dni
if (existe) throw new Exception ("Se encontro un dni ya ingresado");//lanzamos una excepcion
else{
  this.listaDeAlumnos.add(alumno);//si no existe dni duplicados agregamos a una lista
}
}

public List<Alumno> getListaDeAlumnos() {
    return listaDeAlumnos;
}
  
public String toString(){
String datos="";
for(Alumno a:listaDeAlumnos){
   datos+="\nNombre: "+a.getNombre()+"\nDNI: "+a.getDni()+"\nTelefono: "+a.getTelefono()+"\n";
}
  return datos;
} 

}
```

Clase Alumnno:

```
public class Alumno{

//Atributos
private String telefono;
private int  dni;
private String nombre;

//constructor

public Alumno(String telefono,int dni,String nombre){
this.telefono=telefono;
this.dni=dni;
this.nombre=nombre;

}

//Getters y Setters
 
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
 
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
 
public int getDni() {
    return dni;
}
 
public void setDni(int dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}
 
public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}
 
public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

}
```

Clase Main

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Curso curso1=new Curso();
    //Uso de try catch para evaluar que no se ingrese un alumno con un dni ya ingresado
    try{
    curso1.agregar("437-65656",70151923,"Gabriel");
   }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }

    try{
    curso1.agregar("456-56566",70151923,"Juan");
   }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }

   try{
    curso1.agregar("456-56530",70151566,"Lucas");
   }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }

   System.out.println(curso1.toString());

}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]